# Connector pinout review

Tags: connector, pinout, review

I am designing a system around a bus using DIN 41612 connectors. I have come up with the following pinout for my connector taking into account the following requirements :

- Each signal pin should have a ground pin next to it for better ground return paths
- The boards is rated at 30W coming from the 12V pins of the connector.

[image: Connector pinout]

With this design, 12V pins shouldn't exceed 625mA as each pins of the connector can handle 2A of current.

Is this a good pinout or am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Comment: What's the speed of your signals? Single-ended or differential? I'd say this is too few ground pins by a factor of >2, but if all these signals are very low speed, we could shrug this off. Generally, you'd want a ground pin not only to be *a* neighbor, but *the closest* neighbor of a signal pin. Assuming proper decoupling, you can, however, treat your +12V as ground pin when it comes to signal integrity.

Comment: The signals are single-ended and I'd like them to be at least 30 to 50MHz. What do you mean by *the closest* ? Closest as there shouldn't be any other pin as close to it ?

Comment: closest as in "there shouldn't be another signal pin geometrically closer than the next ground or VCC pin"; in your case, there's several instances where the direct neighbor (one pitch of 2.5mm) is a signal and there's a ground diagonally adjacent, but since \$\sqrt2>1\$, that's not as good.

Comment: Also consider where the grounds will be on the mating cable, if you're using a cable and not board-to-board. Ideally you'd have a ground on either side of every signal cable if using a ribbon cable, or one twisted with every signal if it's twisted pair, etc. If this is board to board, that's not a concern.

Comment: Ok I see, so there is only an issue with the pins in the ground pins' diagonals right ?

Comment: It will be connected to a backplane pcb so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So if the *closest* condition is met, what kind of speeds could we be talking about ?